# RewriteRule not working after migration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an `.htaccess` file that was on a server:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteRule ^machine/register.* register.php

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

For requests to the server at `/machine/register?id=....` this used to work. I then migrated servers and now its returning a 404.

I enabled RewriteLog and it shows:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /machine/register
(1) pass through /machine/register
```

I checked the file permission on `register.php` and it belongs to the same owner as the rest of the files and has permissions 666. What is the problem here?

Comment: Where is your htaccess file?

Comment: in the directory of the folder

Comment: You mean the `machine` folder or the document root?

Comment: And the register.php file is in the document root too?

Comment: yessir, it is there as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the configuration had the following:

```
<Directory ...path>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

I changed this to:

```
<Directory ...path>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and it worked. Ill leave this here if someone else runs into this issue.